# Move files from one parent folder to another folder which resides inside the parent folder in s3 bucket with or without s3.list_objects?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to move files from one parent folder to another folder which resides inside the parent folder in s3 bucket with or without s3.list_objects.

example: I want to move file everyday one time from `s3://mybucket/landing/file.txt` to `s3://mybucket/landing/archive/$date/file.txt`

As you can see the key is changing but still has parent key as `landing/`.

AWS Lambda python example: The code will copy the files to `s3://mybucket/landing/archive/<somedate>file.txt` and in next run it will do like
`s3://mybucket/landing/archive/archive/$date/file.txt`

```py
# Get a list of all the objects (i.e., files) in the source bucket

    objects = s3.list_objects(Bucket=source_bucket_name)['Contents'] 
    # Loop through each object and copy it to the destination bucket

    for obj in objects:

        file_name = obj['Key']

        s3.copy_object(Bucket=destination_bucket_name, CopySource={'Bucket': source_bucket_name, 'Key': file_name}, Key=file_name)

        s3.delete_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name, Key=file_name)
```

If I say, get all objects (with `prefix = landing`) from the bucket and copy and delete the objects, my get all objects will include everything from `s3://mybucket/landing/archive/` folder as well, which I can still filter and ignore files after `/archive` but I really do not need anything from this folder, hence would like to limit my get object call to be less expensive and also I think there is a limit of 1000 in one call.

Comment: there is no exclude functionality when listing objects.  A better idea would be to put `archive` somewhere  that doesn't start with the `landing/` prefix

Comment: Instead of moving the objects once per day, have you considered using an S3 Event to trigger an AWS Lambda function for each object _at the time they are created?_ That way, they can be moved immediately and it does not require any `list_objects()` calls since the Bucket and Key are passed to the Lambda function. The Lambda function would still be called for any object within `landing/`, but the process is simplified.

Comment: that would be ideal but my use case does not allows me to move objects once they are created ,I can only move all the files at the end of all the processing.

Comment: @erik258 that's my thought process too.